# Send message from option page to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In chrome documentation, we can send message from option page by using:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage
```

We cannot use:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage
```

I want to send message from option page to content script. Can I do it directly?
This is my option page script:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var radio = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio][name=quality]");
    for(i=0; i<radio.length; i++)
    radio[i].addEventListener("change", function(){
        val = this.id;
        localStorage.setItem("youtube_filter_video_quality", val);
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"youtube_filter_video_quality": val});
    });
});
```

And here is content script:

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            if(request.youtube_filter_video_quality!==undefined){
                console.log(request.youtube_filter_video_quality);
            }
        }
    );
```

And here is manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "__MSG_name__",
    "short_name": "__MSG_short_name__",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version":"1.5.0.0",
    "description": "__MSG_description__",
    "default_locale": "en",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "48.png",
        "default_title": "__MSG_default_title__",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background":{
        "page":"background.html",
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches": [ "*://*.youtube.com/*" ],
        "css": ["app_player.css"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webNavigation"
    ],
    "icons": {
            "64":"64.png",
            "48": "48.png",
            "32":"32.png",
            "16": "16.png",
            "128": "128.png"
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "options_ui": {
        "chrome_style": true,
        "page": "option.html"
    }
}
```

The `console.log` cannot write anything (blank).

Comment: `We cannot use` - you're referring to something that is not an option page. An option page of an extension, which is displayed on chrome://extensions page, has chrome-extension:// URL so it can do everything an extension can do, including chrome.tabs.sendMessage.

Comment: Something looks like this: After I configure on option page, I click on apply. My extension will handle action with applied parameters. I want to send message from this option page at onclick. That is my need. Here is from chrome documentation: "If your options page sends a message using runtime.connect or runtime.sendMessage, the Sender's tab won't be set, and the Sender's URL will be your options page URL."

Comment: That quote from documentation does not apply to chrome.tabs.sendMessage.

Comment: I tried to use both runtime.sendMessage and tabs.sendMessage, but same result. The console.log cannot write anything? Any error in my code?

Comment: You didn't show your code that uses chrome.tabs.sendMessage. It will be different because this function needs a tab id as the first parameter.

Comment: chrome.tabs.query({url:['*://*.youtube.com/*']}, function (tabs){
   for(i=0; i<tabs.length; i++)
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, {"youtube_filter_video_quality": val});
  });

Comment: It works :) Sorry! I don't know why chrome.runtime.sendMessage didnt work.

Comment: No. DOMContentLoaded is in option page. Content script doesn't have that listener.

Comment: So does it work now or not?

Comment: Worked with tabs.sendMessage, didn't work with runtime.sendMessage